# How to handle Selenium Element not found in the cache Exception

Tags: selenium

```
nextbutton.Click(); //Click action on current page
System.out.println("entered next page"); // validating code on above click action. reading this line ensures above line got executed successfully. 

driver.findElement(By.id("CardName")).clear();//Element in next page.
```

getting exception as Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up.

Unable to identify root cause, i am able to see my web page is taken to next page(page flow visible) on `nextbutton.Click()` action, but in console my check out.s.o.p"`System.out.println("entered next page");`" is not printed.

Could some one please help me on this.

I tried, wait, refresh, sleep, for loop for identifying element.. issue i identified is script is being terminated at click action but where as on web page i am able to see next page getting loaded.

Comment: Share code and website please.

Comment: Please provide the locator for the element nextbutton.

Comment: Are you using PageFactory ?

Answer (score 1):

> Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it
>   was looked up.

this exception happends when you initialize some collection with webelements, the page is changed and the collection not initialize again.

look where you have something that was initialize before the click and you want to use it after, for proper use you need to initialize it again.